# Regex to Replace filepath in a string with some other filepath in Java

Tags: java, regex, string, replace

I have a below text file in String **'str'**

```
 # Configuration file for the Jakarta ISAPI Redirector

# The path to the ISAPI Redirector Extension, relative to the website
# This must be in a virtual directory with execute privileges
extension_uri=/jakarta/isapi_redirect.dll

# Full path to the log file for the ISAPI Redirector
log_file=C:\\\\Programs\\\\Org\\\\Pro\\\\Client\\\\apache-tomcat-8.0.33\\\\logs\\\\isapi_redirect.log

# Log level (debug, info, warn, error or trace)
log_level=info

# Full path to the workers.properties file
worker_file=C:\\\\Programs\\\\Org\\\\Pro\\\\Client\\\\apache-tomcat-8.0.33\\\\conf\\\\workers.properties

# Full path to the uriworkermap.properties file
worker_mount_file=C:\\\\Programs\\\\Org\\\\Pro\\\\Client\\\\apache-tomcat-8.0.33\\\\conf\\\\uriworkermap.properties
```

and i want to replace all occurrences of

```
C:\\\\Programs\\\\Org\\\\Pro\\\\Client\\\\apache-tomcat-8.0.33
```

with

```
C:\\\\Program Files\\\\Apache Software Foundation\\\\Tomcat 9.0
```

so that my final **'str'** looks like below

```
# Configuration file for the Jakarta ISAPI Redirector

# The path to the ISAPI Redirector Extension, relative to the website
# This must be in a virtual directory with execute privileges
extension_uri=/jakarta/isapi_redirect.dll

# Full path to the log file for the ISAPI Redirector
log_file=C:\\\\Program Files\\\\Apache Software Foundation\\\\Tomcat 9.0\\\\logs\\\\isapi_redirect.log

# Log level (debug, info, warn, error or trace)
log_level=info

# Full path to the workers.properties file
worker_file=C:\\\\Program Files\\\\Apache Software Foundation\\\\Tomcat 9.0\\\\conf\\\\workers.properties

# Full path to the uriworkermap.properties file
worker_mount_file=C:\\\\Program Files\\\\Apache Software Foundation\\\\Tomcat 9.0\\\\conf\\\\uriworkermap.properties
```

Basically i want to replace filepath after '=' till i encounter 'apache'. this 'apache' could sometimes be 'Tomcat' as well

I visited almost every answers/solutions in stackoverflow and tried to tweak them but none of them yield desired output.

I have tried around 8-9 Regex since its too many i didn't post them

Comment: You don't need regex, you can simply do `str = str.replace("C:\\\\Programs\\\\Org\\\\Pro\\\\Client\\\\apache-tomcat-8.0.33", "C:\\\\Program Files\\\\Apache Software Foundation\\\\Tomcat 9.0")`

Comment: What is the unwanted result you're receiving? What code are you using?

Comment: @Titus basically i want to replace filepath after '=' till i encounter 'apache' this apache could sometimes be 'Tomcat' as well

Comment: @shash678 No it doesn't, `replaceAll` does, here is the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace(char,%20char))

Comment: @SagarSN Oh, in that case, you'll need to use regex. That is not evident from your question, you should edit it to be clearer.

Comment: @Titus First word of my question says Regex. Thanks for responding

Comment: @Titus on line 2225 of https://github.com/CyC2018/JDK-Source-Code/blob/master/src/String.java there is a replace method that does appear to be using regex, also the method you linked only takes individual characters I think, so the one on line 2225 would be the one used.

Comment: Your question is bit unclear. When you say "I have a below text file in String 'str'" do you mean that you `string` *represents* such text, or *contains* such string. Difference is that if it `str` represents text ``\\\\`` it should contain string like `"\\\\\\\\"`. Also can you clarify how Titus solutions fails for example provided in question?

Comment: @shash678 There is a `Pattern.LITERAL` there that escapes all the special character from the parameter, it uses regex but it doesn't interpret the parameter as a regular expression.

Comment: @titus ok I understand I just remembered it had something to do with regex.

Comment: @shash678 yes, `replace` method is using regex *engine*, but because of `Pattern.LITERAL` it doesn't "support" regex *syntax*.

Comment: @Pshemo yes string contains such text (converted textfile using toString())

Comment: @shash678 That is the `replaceAll` function, I also confuse them all the time, I had the documentation handy because I had to take a look to make sure before I've posted my first comment.

Comment: @Pshemo Titus solution fails next time when i want to replace. suppose if i want to replace `C:\\\\Program Files\\\\Apache Software Foundation\\\\Tomcat 9.0` with `C:\\\\Program Files\\\\Apache Software Foundation\\\\Tomcat 9.7`. We should also consider '=' where filepath name actually starts

Comment: @SagarSN "yes string contains such text" just to make sure, if you `System.out.println(str)` you actually see `... C:\\Program Files ...` not `... C:\\\\Program Files ...`.

Comment: All i want is `=C:\\\\Program Files\\\\Apache Software Foundation\\\\Tomcat 9.0\\\\` same 4 slashes format. i write same string to file

Answer (score 0):

**"\"** is a meta character in Regex which means you should code `"\\"` , meanwhile **"\"** needs to be escaped in Java so that If you want to match a **"\"** character you should code `"\\\\"`.